# New-S3CJob: Invalid Request

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, s3-batch

I am trying to create a S3 Batch Job using the AWS powershell command New-S3CJob to copy some S3 Objects from one bucket to another. I have the manifest file in the source bucket itself.

The command i am invoking looks like this:

```
New-S3CJob -AccountId $accountId -S3PutObjectCopy_StorageClass STANDARD -S3PutObjectCopy_TargetKeyPrefix TESTBK -S3PutObjectCopy_TargetResource "arn:aws:s3:::$destinationBucket" -RoleArn $iamRoleArn -Report_Bucket "arn:aws:s3:::$sourceBucket" -Priority 10 -ManifestOutputLocation_Bucket "arn:aws:s3:::$sourceBucket" -ManifestOutputLocation_ManifestPrefix "manifest.csv" -ConfirmationRequired $false
```

What am i missing?

I tried creating the S3 Batch Operation Job using AWS Powershell Module. I expect a job to be created for a copy operation between source and destination bucket. I am not able to understand which parameters to use.

The script looks like this:

```
$accountId = (Get-STSCallerIdentity).Account
$iamRoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::${accountId}:role/S3BatchOperationRole-us-east-1"
$sourceBucket = "sourceBucket"
$destinationBucket = "destinationBucket"

# Command to Create Job
New-S3CJob -AccountId $accountId -S3PutObjectCopy_StorageClass STANDARD -S3PutObjectCopy_TargetKeyPrefix TESTBK -S3PutObjectCopy_TargetResource "arn:aws:s3:::$destinationBucket" -RoleArn $iamRoleArn -Report_Bucket "arn:aws:s3:::$sourceBucket" -Priority 10 -ManifestOutputLocation_Bucket "arn:aws:s3:::$sourceBucket" -ManifestOutputLocation_ManifestPrefix "manifest.csv" -ConfirmationRequired $false
```

It is throwing invalid request error.

Comment: aws s3control create-job --region "us-east-1" --account-id $accountId --operation $operation --manifest $manifest --report $report --priority 10 --role-arn $iamRoleArn --client-request-token $clienReqToken --description "Copy Sql Backups" --no-confirmation-required

I have tried this aws cli command now. Throwing Invalid Job Operation. The operation json looks like this:

"Operation": {
                "S3PutObjectCopy": {
                    "TargetResource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/TSTBK"
                }
            }

Comment: Found the answer. The TargetResourceProperty should only have the S3 Bucket's arn without the path to the prefix.